# Преоброазования IEnumerable в IEnumerable<Т>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Есть описанная в LINQ MS SQL таблица "Channel". Я анализирую какие изменения (updates) были выполнены именно в таблице «Channel»:

IEnumerable test = dataAvZVKDataContext.GetChangeSet().Updates.OfType();

Для преоброазования IEnumerable test в IEnumerable test:

```
IEnumerable<Canal> test = dataAvZVKDataContext.GetChangeSet().Updates.OfType<Channel>().Select(x => x);
```

Наверно должно быть более изящное решение, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: А зачем `.Select(x => x)`

Comment: Для преобразования IEnumerable в IEnumerable<Т>

Comment: Нет, ничего изящнее `Cast<>()` (ну или `OfType<>()`) нет